# Unique name for element inside of Listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, uwp

I'm running into a problem where I need to name a UIElement inside of a ListBox, but I can't because it's going to be looping through and obviously can't have a million little TextBlock's running around with the same name.

Here's my a simplified version of my ListBox:

```
<ListBox Background="Transparent">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />                            
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
            <RelativePanel">
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=Hub}" FontWeight="Bold" Name="firstText" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="{Binding Path=Stats.Pages}" Name="secondText" RelativePanel.RightOf="firstText" />
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState>
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1100" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="secondText.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="hubText" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState>
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="secondText.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="firstText" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </RelativePanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

For my situation I'm trying to use AdaptiveTriggers on the RelativePanel to set the positioning of the `secondText` TextBlock to the right of `firstText` when there is a wider screen, and underneath when there is a smaller screen.

As far as I know, the only way I can change this is using the Setter on the name, so I'd need a unique one somehow? Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:** Okay, so it compiled and ran fine (RelativePanel.RightOf is working initially), but the AdaptiveTriggers don't work, and VS is throwing a tissy about the markup. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to wrap the elements inside your `DataTemplate` with a `UserControl`.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <UserControl>
            <RelativePanel>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Wide">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="1100" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="secondText.(RelativePanel.RightOf)" Value="hubText" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                                <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="secondText.(RelativePanel.Below)" Value="firstText" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <TextBlock FontSize=" 12" Text="hub" FontWeight="Bold" x:Name="hubText" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="first" x:Name="firstText" RelativePanel.RightOf="hubText" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="12" Text="second" x:Name="secondText" RelativePanel.RightOf="firstText" />
            </RelativePanel>
        </UserControl>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Note that I also changed the `TextBlock`'s `Name` to `x:Name`.

Comment: Also, make sure you *name* your `VisualState`s too.

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.